# Is it possible to sort Google Analytics Data by a dimension not queried?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I want to get display EventCategory and pageViews in a Google DataChart Bar chart.  My trouble is that I want to sort the bar chart so by pageTitle.  When I ask for the sort I get the error saying the dimension or metric ga:pageTitle is not in the query.

If I add the dimension to the query I get an error saying everything on an axis must be the same Type.

So I cant find a way to get the data in the query and not display it in the chart. Here is where I build the chart

```
var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({

    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:eventLabel;ga:pageTitle' ,
            'metrics' : 'ga:pageviews',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
            'filters': "ga:dimension1=="+userid,
            'sort' : 'ga:pageTitle',
    }, 
    chart: { 
      type: 'BAR',
      container: 'timeline',
            options: {
                title:'Page Views',
                height:'800',
                width: '500',
                hAxis: {
                 title:'Views',
                 minValue:0,
                 gridlines:{count:7}
                },
                vAxis:{title:'Page'} 
            }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the chart error, but it doesn't make sense to use the metric ga:pageviews with ga:event*, that answer should always be no results as events are separate from pageviews.. Have you tried an event appropriate metric such as ga:totalEvents?

Comment: @lossleader is correct, in general it doesn't make sense to query for event category and page title in the same query. Event category data is typically only sent with event hits not with pageview hits.

Comment: GA has a  report to show which events happened on what pages, so it's not like the idea to combine the two is totally crazy (although I'm not sure about the use case here). Of course it is always possible to just retrieve a GA result with the pageTitle via gapi.analytics.report.Data and remove the offending data column before you pass the result to a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a few different questions in your question, so I'll try to address each of them:

**1) Is is possible to sort by a dimension not queried?**

No, and if you think about it, that makes sense. If you don't include a dimension in the query, you won't get any results back for that data set, and so how could you sort on something that isn't in the result set?

**2) Why do I get the error "everything on an axis must be the same Type"?**

This is because the Embed API `DataChart` component uses Google Charts under the hood, and Google Charts requires all data along the same axis to be of the same type.

But again, this makes sense because how would you even draw a chart where the x-axis had two different datatypes?

**3) So how can I visualize the results of this query?**

If you want to query for both `ga:eventCategory` and `ga:pageTitle` at the same time, then your only option for visualization is a table chart.